# Primefaces progressBar is not showing up

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

This is the code in the body of my .xhtml file. The bars were showing before (I don't remember changing anything significant) but now just the value is displayed.

```
<p:progressBar value="#{bean.value}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated"/>

<p:progressBar id="progress" interval="100" rendered="true" ajax="true" value="#{bean.value}" widgetVar="pbAjax" labelTemplate="{value}%" style="width:300px; font-size:12px"/>
```

The second bar is derived from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531248/primefaces-dynamic-label-for-progressbar/) but the problem still remains the same.

```
<p:progressBar value="50" labelTemplate="{value}%" displayOnly="true"/>
```

This is the code from [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/progressBar.jsf), which also does not show up as a bar but just as a value.

I would appreciate it you could clarify if I have some major misunderstanding of how the progressBar works.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug or your browser's WebDevelopment Tools to check if the progressbar is properly rendered:

1. Check for Javascript Errors
2. Is the right CSS Style applied or are you overwriting primefaces css classes?
3. Are you using your own JQuery Version? It can come to conflicts between your JQuery and Primefaces' one.